# Check if data exist in another table using orWhereHas laravel eloquent query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables users and attendances.
In attendances table contain user attendance for `present_date` and `present_type` wise .
`present_type` is kept for shift. If shift, user may have multiple attendance for a date.
For this reason one user may have many rows in attendance table.
I want to show all users and 
checked=> if attendance found for specific day and type for the user
unchecked=>if attendance not exist for the day in the view while loop.

```
$userList = User::              
             orWhereHas('userAttendance', function ($q) use ($attDate,$type) {
                 $q->where('present_date', $attDate);
                 $q->wherePresentType($type);
             })->get();
```

In blade file loop:

```
  @foreach($userList as $key => $user)
 <input value="{{$user->id}}" title="" type="checkbox"
                                      @if($user->userAttendance)
                                      checked="checked" data-exist-id="{{$user->userAttendance->id}}"
                                      @endif class="action-normal" />
```

But this is not working as expected.
It makes checked if row exist on attendance table without filtering date or type written in `orWhereHas` Clasure!

I want to check if a specific day's (if present_type is for not shift) data exist on attendance table without making another query to keep limited db hit.

I can do this using making a function in User model where the function get parameter from blade file while loop. But i don't want to do extra db query.

Is there any way to do using pure eloquent? 
Can i check it for a user at the time of loop using data sent from controller function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why the orWhereHas ?

Try this:

```
$userList = User::query()              
             ->with(['userAttendance' => function($q) use($attDate,$type) {
                 $q->where('present_date', $attDate);
                 $q->wherePresentType($type);
             }])
             ->get();
```

It's better to load the relation, avoiding multiple queries in the view.

Edit: This will give you all users and load the proper userAttendance relation, when conditions met.

Comment: But this will return only those user who have attendance. I need leftjoin like query in eloquent. I need all users and check in view if has attendance

Comment: @Fawel So remove the ->whereHas altogether.